# how to change the components in UITableVIewCell dynamicly

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am creating a `UITabelViewCell` looks like the the feed in Facebook which contains feed content, images, comments and so on.

To simplify the problem, let`s consider only a`UILabel`on the top and a`UIImageView` below the lable. All the constraints are set properly and the height of the cell is caculated dynamicly according to the constraints.

The challenge I face is that sometimes the feed only have content and sometimes it contains both content and images. I do not want to create two `UITabelViewCell`, cause it will make it harder to maintain.

The method I use now is remove the `UIImageView` if I find no image in the data, but I have to add it back when necessary, and all these can be done at "`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`". But I don`t think it is a good solution, can some one show me some good points, thanks!

Comment: I'll definitely go with two view which is in fact a pretty easier way to handle views. I don't know why you think you have trouble using that. Is there a design implication?

Comment: @AtifImran you mean create two UITableViewCell ?

Comment: All you have to do is to pick the right cell.

Comment: @AtifImran But that may make the shared component harder to maintan, I have to do the same work repeated.

Comment: share a sample project file and i will do the easiest solution in that.